# What is the need of passing the arguments in python functions if the variables are declared globally?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables, parameters

```
a = 13
b = 12

def add():
    return a + b

def add2(a, b):    # why to pass a and b?
    return a + b

print(add())   # result 25
print(add2(a, b))    #result 25
```

why do we need to pass the arguments to the python function if we can use the values/variables without passing them to functions?

Comment: Why would you even *have* function and variables if all you want is 25?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, it is not necessary to pass arguments because you are always adding the same two variables. But if you wanted to have a function that could add any two variables, how would the function know which two variables to add? In the example below, I have three variables and a function to add two of them:

```py
def add():
    return a + b

a = 5
b = 7
c = 10

print(add())  # 12
# No way to add a + c or b + c
```

The problem is that if I want to add `c` to one of the other variables, I have no way of doing this. We can define a function which takes two arguments to solve this problem:

```py
def add(n1, n2):
    return n1 + n2

a = 5
b = 7
c = 10

print(add(a, b))  # 12
print(add(a, c))  # 15
print(add(b, c))  # 17
```

So, in short, you only need to pass arguments to a function if you aren't sure which global variables the function will need